# How can I access rails methods in a ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a ruby script in my rails app in the script directory. How can I access the `in_time_zone` method in the script?

Comment: Is it related to the Rails app? Will you need access to your app's models, etc? What's the purpose of the script? Perhaps you can make it a rake task that includes the Rails environment.

Comment: No, just want access to that one helper method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need that one method, you could just whack `require 'active_support/all'` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 1):

It's in `active_support/core_ext`.

```
> require 'active_support/core_ext'
 => true
> d = DateTime.new(2000)
 => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 +0000 
> d.in_time_zone("Alaska")
 => Fri, 31 Dec 1999 15:00:00 AKST -09:00 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom rake task, and then access everything in your application for instance. You can check this [great screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks)